# Como otimizar uma imagem para web?

Tags: c#, compressão-de-imagem

No meu site alguém faz um upload de uma imagem (ex: 800x600). Eu gostaria de salvar esta imagem em uma pasta, mas reduzindo o tamanho em disco o máximo possível sem perder muito a qualidade.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca de compressão como a LZMA (7zip) para comprimir a imagem, assim você conseguem armazenar ela ocupando pouco espaço no disco e mantém a qualidade. Ou elas estão salvas em um banco de dados?

Comment: Se estão no formato PNG/JPG, então já devem estar bem compactas (aplicar outro algoritmo de compressão por cima não deve fazer muita diferença). Uma opção é você abrir a imagem e remover pequenas diferenças entre pixels, fazendo com que cores muito próximas fiquem iguais. Isso vai fazer a compressão do PNG ser muito mais eficiente.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quais formatos de imagem?

Um jeito simples de comprimir imagens é utilizar as classes do namespace [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.aspx):

```
public static void ComprimirImagem(Image imagem, long qualidade, string filepath)
{
    var param = new EncoderParameters(1);
    param.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, qualidade);
    var codec = ObterCodec(imagem.RawFormat);
    imagem.Save(filepath, codec, param);
}

private static ImageCodecInfo ObterCodec(ImageFormat formato)
{
    var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == formato.Guid);
    if (codec == null) throw new NotSupportedException();
    return codec;
}
```

Adaptado [daqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb882583.aspx).

Teoricamente o código funcionaria com qualquer formato de imagem que o sistema possuísse codec, mas segundo meus testes apenas com imagens no formato JPEG houve compressão (as outras mantiveram o mesmo tamanho independente da qualidade passada).

Fiz alguns testes com [esta imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk86o.jpg) (265.94 KB), os resultados foram:

- Qualidade `80L`:  54.3 KB ([imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REKpk.jpg))
- Qualidade `60L`:  40.6 KB ([imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibhcD.jpg))
- Qualidade `40L`:  33.5 KB ([imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tnyi.jpg))
- Qualidade `20L`:  25.4 KB ([imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXA05.jpg))

P.S..: As imagens dos links postados não representam *exatamente* a qualidade que obtive em meus testes, pois o [imgur](http://imgur.com/) fez também sua própria otimização; é apenas para ter uma noção da perda de qualidade.

---

Outras referências

- A biblioteca [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) ([NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/)) possui alguns os [métodos de compressão](http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics#formats--compression).
- O [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/) possui uma [API](https://tinypng.com/developers) (grátis até 500 imagens/mês).
- O [Dot Net Perls possui um tutorial sobre otimização de png](http://www.dotnetperls.com/png) (utilizando a ferramenta [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)).

Answer (score 1):

O exemplo do talles, tá correto, a conversão para os outros modelos basta no formado passar como o código abaixo.

```
var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().First(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
```